# Nextjs Loading.tsx component not showing on windows server 2019, but on macbook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

I have built a small test application:
https://github.com/Relbot/testapp.git

if you open the initial page localhost:3000 you should see
"Hier steht ein toller text"
at the top of the page and below a loading state ("loading...") for 3 seconds and after this the text "dies tet hat länger gedauert zu laden" should appear.

Everything works fine if I run this on my macbook ("npm run dev").

But if I run this on a Windows Server 2019. The loading state doesn't appear. It shows nothing for 3 seconds and then the whole page with all the text is shown.

What can be the problem on the windows server?

Any help
appreciated

Comment: Could this be something with the firewall or some ports that are not open on the windows server 2019 from my client ?

Comment: Have a instance running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and there does not seem to be any problem, maybe remove the `node_modules`, `.next` folder any your `yarn.lock` and then reinstall and rebuild.

Comment: Already tried this. I came to the conclusion that it can only be something with the firewall. But I can not figure out what I need to change because I get no errors

Comment: What exactly would the firewall have to do with anything in this case? Open an issue inside the Next.js repository. I don't think anyone is able to help here.